# Jenkins with two cucumber reports override each other

Tags: jenkins, plugins, cucumber, google-kubernetes-engine

I've got Jenkins job with 2 stages generating two separate reports (they use `https://plugins.jenkins.io/cucumber-reports/` this plugin and HTML publisher), Jenkins itself is on GKE (so after the job is done and files are generated on the agent they are transferred to master); The issue I've got it that first HTML Report and Cucumber reports are generated properly but when the second stage is run, it overrides some of the files from the first step, resulting in 403 error from Jenkins when checking the report. Any thoughts on how to deal with it?

```
Access to Jenkins was denied you don't have the authorisation to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use ,

**reportTitle: 'name'**

entry in cucumber step , it wont override your report .

Example:

```
step([$class: 'CucumberReportPublisher',
    failedFeaturesNumber: xxx,
    failedScenariosNumber: xxx,
    failedStepsNumber: xxxx,
    fileExcludePattern: '',
    fileIncludePattern: '**/*.json',
    jsonReportDirectory: xxx,
    parallelTesting: false,
    reportTitle: xxx ,     
    pendingStepsNumber: xx,
    skippedStepsNumber: xx,
    trendsLimit: 0,
    undefinedStepsNumber: xx
  ])
```

Jenkins version         : Jenkins 2.230

Cucumber reports plugin : 5.2.0

Comment: that's usefull to know, I already solved it by running one report in one job and the other in other, and making one job calling bouth of those jobs

Comment: Why dont you mark the answer as correct? That is the correct answer as per the documentation.